# How to switch control from child window to parent window if the child window close on clicking a button?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:

- Click on Audit button in parent window
- Child window is loaded.
- Switch the control to child window
- Click on OK button in child window.
- Window closes
- Continue the testing from parent window

Here I am facing the challenge in switching to parent window after clicking OK button. As the window itself get closed.

Selenium Webdriver : 2.48

Answer (score 0):

You already have ids of all your windows.

```
 driver.switchTo.window(parentWindow);
```

Comment: But since clicking on Ok button closes the window, 'driver' will be not be usable for switching the window again.

Comment: can you share the relevant HTML

Comment: Not sure why you need the HTML here?